# Scrape ASIN from Amazon's Search page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I try to scrape the ASIN numbers on Amazon. Please note that this is not about the product details (like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRVRIh3GZgI), but this is when you search for a keyword (in this example "trimmer", try this: 
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=trimmer&ref=nb_sb_noss_2). The results are many products, I am able to scrape all the Titles.

What is not visible is the ASIN (which is a unique Amazon number). I saw, while inspecting the HTML a link in the text (href), which is containing the ASIN number. In the example below, the ASIN = B01MSHQ5IQ

```
<a class="a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="/Philips-Norelco-Groomer-MG3750-50/dp/B01MSHQ5IQ/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=trimmer&amp;qid=1554462204&amp;s=gateway&amp;sr=8-3">
```

Ending with my question: **How can I retrieve all the Product Titles AND ASIN numbers on the page?** For example:

```
Number     Title                       ASIN
 1       Braun, Beardtrimmer          B07JH1LLYR 
 2       TNT Pro Series Waist         B00R84J2PK
 ...     ...                          ...
```

So far, I am using scrapy (but also open for other Python solutions) and I am able to scrape the Titles.

My code so far:

First run in the command line:

```
scrapy startproject tutorial
```

Then, adjust the files in the Spider (see example 1) and items.py (see example 2).

Example 1

```
class AmazonProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "AmazonDeals"
  allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]

  #Use working product URL below
  start_urls = [
     "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=trimmer&ref=nb_sb_noss_2"         

]
 ## scrapy crawl AmazonDeals -o Asin_Titles.json

  def parse(self, response):
      items = AmazonItem()


      Title = response.css('.a-text-normal').css('::text').extract()
      items['title_Products'] = Title 
      yield items
```

As requested by @glhr, adding the **items.py** code:

Example 2

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy

class AmazonItem(scrapy.Item):
  # define the fields for your item here like:
  title_Products = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: There's a missing quotation mark in this line: `items['title_Products] = Title`

Comment: Good catch. Have updated the code. Do you perhaps know how we can get the ASIN number? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you share the code for `AmazonItem` so I can run the spider myself?

Comment: Sure, have updated the questions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the link to the product by extracting the `href` attribute of `<a class="a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="...">`:

```
Link = response.css('.a-text-normal').css('a::attr(href)').extract()
```

From a link, you can use a regular expression to extract the ASIN number from the link:

```
(?<=dp/)[A-Z0-9]{10}
```

The regular expression above will match 10 characters (either uppercase letters or numbers) preceded by `dp/`. See demo here: https://regex101.com/r/mLMv3k/1

Here's a working implementation of the `parse()` method:

```
def parse(self, response):
    Link = response.css('.a-text-normal').css('a::attr(href)').extract()
    Title = response.css('span.a-text-normal').css('::text').extract()

    # for each product, create an AmazonItem, populate the fields and yield the item
    for result in zip(Link,Title):
        item = AmazonItem()
        item['title_Product'] = result[1]
        item['link_Product'] = result[0]
        # extract ASIN from link
        ASIN = re.findall(r"(?<=dp/)[A-Z0-9]{10}",result[0])[0]
        item['ASIN_Product'] = ASIN
        yield item
```

This requires extending `AmazonItem` with new fields:

```
class AmazonItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    title_Product = scrapy.Field()
    link_Product = scrapy.Field()
    ASIN_Product = scrapy.Field()
```

Sample output:

```
{'ASIN_Product': 'B01MSHQ5IQ',
 'link_Product': '/Philips-Norelco-Groomer-MG3750-50/dp/B01MSHQ5IQ',
 'title_Product': 'Philips Norelco Multigroom Series 3000, 13 attachments, '
                  'FFP, MG3750'}
{'ASIN_Product': 'B01MSHQ5IQ',
 'link_Product': '/Philips-Norelco-Groomer-MG3750-50/dp/B01MSHQ5IQ',
 'title_Product': 'Philips Norelco Multi Groomer MG7750/49-23 piece, beard, '
                  'body, face, nose, and ear hair trimmer, shaver, and clipper'}
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55534679-AmazonSpider

To write the output to a JSON file, simply specify feed export settings in the spider:

```
class AmazonProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "AmazonDeals"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.amazon.com/s?k=trimmer&ref=nb_sb_noss_2"]
    custom_settings = {
            'FEED_URI' : 'Asin_Titles.json',
            'FEED_FORMAT' : 'json'
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to run your code, but I received an error: 

      in parse
    ASIN = re.findall(r"(?<=dp/)[A-Z0-9]{10}",result[0])[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: I will use your example instead. Last question: is it possible in your example to write (save) the scraped items as JSON file? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but do you have the same issue:    

raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()

ReactorNotRestartable

Comment: No, sounds like you're trying to run several instances of the crawler at once. Make sure scrapy is not already running.

Comment: You were totally right. I was running another Scrapy via the command line. Is it also possible with your way to print the URL? I tried to do it with adding another line:  item["url_response'] = response.url  (but that is not working). Sorry bothering you.

Comment: As long as you add a `url_response` field in `AmazonItem` (with `url_response = scrapy.Field()`) and put `item['url_response'] = response.url` inside the `for` loop, yes it works fine. Added it to the demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55534679-AmazonSpider

Comment: Everything is solved. I know that this is against the rules, but thank you! Really appreciated.